# Regex: Match specific characters in any order without more occurrences of each character than specified

Tags: regex

I have a list of characters, e.g. `{o, b, c, c, d, o, f}`.

If a string contains characters that are not in that list, I don't want it to be a match. If a string contains more occurrences of a character than there are occurrences of that character in that list, I don't want it to be a match.

The characters in the string may occur in any order, and all characters don't have to appear. In the above example `"foo"` should be a match but not `"fooo"`.

I have for instance narrowed the above example down to `(o{0,2}b?c{0,2}d?f?)`, but that doesn't quite work since the order matters in that regex. I get a match for `"oof"` but not for `"foo"`.

Comment: A task involving irregularities. Sounds like the perfect job for RegEx. Perhaps writing a parser via RegEx should be your next task.

Comment: `If a string contains more occurrences of a character than there are occurrences of that character in that list` - How is this supposed to be done in a regex ?? The regex has to be preformed (constant), the list can change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As gview says, regex is not the right tool. However, if your regex engine supports lookahead, you can use this:

```
^(?=(?:[^o]*o){0,2}[^o]*$)(?=(?:[^c]*c){0,2}[^c]*$)(?=[^b]*b?[^b]*$)(?=[^d]*d?[^d]*$)(?=[^f]*f?[^f]*$)[obcdf]+$
```

Its a bit long but very simple:

The string is matched with `^[obcdf]+$` (note the use of anchors).

The lookaheads `(?=...)` are only checks (followed by):

```
(?=(?:[^o]*o){0,2}[^o]*$)   # no more than 2 o until the end

(?=[^b]*b?[^b]*$) # no more than 1 b until the end
```

Each subpattern in lookaheads describes the whole string.

Comment: Wow, I had a feeling it could be done with lookaheads, but I never imagined it would be that gnarly.

Comment: Inconsistency `[^d*]` vs `[^f]*`

Comment: @gseattle: good catch

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that regex is the right tool for that requirement.  I would create a simple array with a count of the characters in the whitelist.  If your language has associative arrays then key by the letter and have the number of occurrences in the array element.

Then process the word character by character, attempting a match in the associative array, and decrementing the available count.

It fails, if either:

- you don't have a match for a letter in your array
- you match but there isn't a count left for the matched letter.

Comment: +1 - I agree with this, but would love to know if this **could** be done via regex!! :)

Answer (score 5):

Another way might work as well

```
 # ^(?!(?:.*o){3})(?!(?:.*c){3})(?!(?:.*b){2})(?!(?:.*d){2})(?!(?:.*f){2})[obcdf]+$

 ^                 # BOS
 (?! (?:.* o){3} ) # not more than 2 'o'
 (?! (?:.* c){3} ) # not more than 2 'c'
 (?! (?:.* b){2} ) # not more than 1 'b'
 (?! (?:.* d){2} ) # not more than 1 'd'
 (?! (?:.* f){2} ) # not more than 1 'f'
 [obcdf]+          # can only be these
 $                 # EOS
```

Comment: I like the use of negative lookaheads here.   Seems easier to understand than using the positive ones.

Comment: @gview - Thanks. I agree, it reduces the clutter.

Comment: @sln: it's indeed shorter in this way!

Comment: @sln: and will fail faster if you change `.*` with a negated character class.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte - Yep, `[^o]* o` probably would fail faster, might depend on where the o's are.