# How to validate if there are specific characters in input without checking their order

Tags: java, regex

Is there are a simple way to ensure with RegEx that input String will contain exactly, let's say one 'a', five 'b, seven 'z' characters - with no order checking?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411445/regex-match-specific-characters-in-any-order-without-more-occurrences-of-each-c

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a great tool to try and test regexes enter your regex and then several strings to see what matches. For example a regex that matches on one of each character is https://regex101.com/r/UtoK45/1

Comment: let's say if you want to make sure that there is only one 'a' in your input then you can use regex: "[.&&[^a]]*[a][.&&[^a]]* It's quite simple but when you want to add more "a" and more characters it becomes much more complicated to check it via that type of regex style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "ordered" way to do your task using regex is as follows:

- Start with `^` anchor.
- Then put 3 positive lookaheads for particular conditions
  (details below).
- And finally put `.*$` matching the whole string.

And now get down to particular conditions and respective lookaheads:

1. A single `a`: `(?=[^a]*a[^a]*$)` - there should be:

   - `[^a]*` - A number of characters different than `a`, possibly 0.
   - `a` - Then just a single `a`.
   - `[^a]*` - Then again a number of characters different than `a`,
     possibly 0.
   - `$` - And finally the end of string.
2. Five times `b`: `(?=[^b]*(?:b[^b]*){5}$)`. This time `b[^b]*` is the
   content of a non-capturing group, needed due to the quantifier after it.
3. Seven times `z`: `(?=[^z]*(?:z[^z]*){7}$)`. Like before, but this
   time the letter in question is `z` and the quantifier is `7`.

So the whole regex can look like below:

```
^(?=[^a]*a[^a]*$)(?=[^b]*(?:b[^b]*){5}$)(?=[^z]*(?:z[^z]*){7}$).*$
```

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/gUxC2C/1

Try to experiment with the content, adding or removing `a`, `b` or `z`
and you will see appearing / disappearing match.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use `StringUtils.countMatches` as described here: [How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

This is not a regex based solution but it is a Java solution. Several answers there show other techniques.